# youtube-dl code returning 0 after running code

Tags: python, python3, youtube-dl

I've been having this problem where whenever I run this block of code:

```
import os
import youtube_dl


songid = os.system(f'youtube-dl "ytsearch:hi there" --get-id')
print(songid)
```

It returns the videos id, but also a random '0' at the end. Could someone help me with this? Thank you so much for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Actually your call

```py
os.system(f'youtube-dl "ytsearch:hi there" --get-id')
```

prints the ID of the video, because that's what your shell command print on stdout; and it return the error code of the command, which is *0* here as the command is sucessfull. And thus your `songid` store that error code, not the ID.

Beside I think you don't use youtube_dl as you intended, because you import the youtube_dl python binding with `import youtube_dl` but you never used it. Instead you call the youtube-dl shell command directly. I think it will be easier to use the python binding and shouldn't need to use `os.system`.